# capacitor in series with lamp

Tags: capacitor

My book says we can't connect a capacitor and a  bulb because it will cause flickering of bulb.Does it mean the cycle of current we see in power curve representation should be discontinuous because we are getting no current till capacitor is charging ? Or maybe I should not believe everything I read ?

Comment: You may need a better book...

Comment: Actually it was like this
A 120v,6W lamp is to be operated in 220V,50Hz supply mains.Calculate what value of 1.non inductive resistance 2.pure inductance and 3.pure capacitance would be required to run lamp on correct voltage.
Which method will be preferred.
After all calculations it was writen that inductor wil be used resistance wastes power and capacitor will cause flickering of bulb.

Comment: In the steady state, the capacitor will not cause the bulb to flicker. However, the turn-on transient depends on the phase of the input waveform. If the supply is turned off at the right moment to leave the cap charged, and then turned on again so the cap voltage adds to the mains waveform, the transient would be very large indeed. But still unlikely to blow the bulb. The inductor has a turn-on transient as well, though due to practical reasons, will not be left 'charged' the wrong way by previous use. Resistor wastes power, cap and inductor are equivalent in power and flickering!

Comment: There is nothing fundamentally about a conventional bulb and capacitor that would cause the bulb to flicker. Either you haven't understood your book, you aren't providing the details to fully justify the assertion or your book is wrong. These are the only options as far as I see it.

Comment: The question was exactly same and the assertion is
the voltage control by inductance is preferred.Because in case of resistance there is wastage of power(i^2r) and in case of pure capacitor there is flickering of bulb because of charging and discharging of capacitor.Hence  best method is connecting inductance in series with bulb.
These are the exacts words written in book.
Currently,I am taking it as a wrong assertion because the current wave we see in power curve  diagram is also continuous means curren is continuous flowing.

Answer (score 1):

No, the bulb should not flicker.
The calculations are as follows:

v bulb  120,
P bulb  6,
V supply    220,
f supply    50,

I bulb  0.05,
R bulb  2400,
Z tot   4400

Z tot squared   19360000,
R bulb squared  5760000,
Z required Squared  13600000,
Z required  3687.817783,

C reqd  8.6314E-07,
L reqd  11.7386985,

To use an inductor would require 12H, so too large for practical purposes.
! capacitor 820nF or 1uF would be OK. Use a plastic capacitor of the full voltage rating of the supply. Some plastic capacitors degrade over time and will result in dimming of the bulb. A good plan would be to use a Y rated capacitor as these are designed to fail open circuit prevent the bulb from exploding if the cap fails. They also are good quality as they are made to meet high standards for safety. You could use a resistor (2k) but it would dissipate 5W.